# Expect a failing Jasmine matcher

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Is there a way to expect a failing Jasmine matcher in a method? The following code shows what I'm trying to do:

```
function test() {
    expect(true).toBe(false);
};

describe("A suite", function() {
  it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {   
    expect(function() {
        test();
    }).toThrow();
  });
});
```

I would like to see this spec marked as "ok". Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at how [Jasmine tests its own Matchers](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/41a813521ba5cf407ea595c8327a63cb266833f3/spec/core/matchers/toEqualSpec.js#L4-L11) you might be able to follow their approach of having separate instances in the same way: one which is the test runner and another which is the runner under test.